# how to install firefox 26 on ubuntu without internet connection

Tags: 12.04

Current version of Ubuntu that I have is 12.04 which do not have internet connection, what is the instruction or command to update the Firefox version from 21 to 26 ?

Answer (score 1):

Version 26.0 is available for download from the [Firefox website](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-26.0&os=linux&lang=en-US)  - go to someone who has internet, download there then copy to a USB flash drive or CD-R. Then, put that media on your system copy the files from that archive file, by clicking on it with your file manager which should call the Archive Manager app to open the file.

Copy them into a folder you name firefox-new in your home directory.

Then delete the contents of your existing Firefox files in `/usr/lib/firefox` and move the new version in there.